# Method with same name as the arguments results to different output

Tags: c++, function, static

Why is the method `payment1` giving a different outpout then `payment2`? `payment2` has the same argument name then the method name (I hope I'm saying this right?). I mean that the code `this->moneysamename+=moneysamename;`. Why can't the compiler differentiate the 2 variables?

Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    protected:
        static int money;
        static int moneysamename;
public:
    virtual void payment1(float money1) = 0;
    virtual void payment2(float moneysamename) = 0;
};

class Worker : public Person
{
public:
    virtual void payment1(float moneyanothername) 
    {
        this->money+= moneyanothername;
        cout << "Worker: " << money << endl;
    };

    virtual void payment2(float moneysamename) 
    {
        this->moneysamename+= moneysamename;
        cout << "Worker: " << moneysamename << endl;
    };
};

void pay1(Person &m, float sum)
{
    m.payment1(sum);
}

void pay2(Person &m, float sum)
{
    m.payment2(sum);
}

int Person::money = 0;
int Person::moneysamename = 0;

int main()
{
    Worker Gaston;

    pay1(Gaston, 200);
    pay1(Gaston, 300);

    pay2(Gaston, 200);
    pay2(Gaston, 300);
}
```

output:

```
Worker: 200
Worker: 500
Worker: 200
Worker: 300
```

Comment: Can't understand the question. Please state exact problem - what is your expected output (and why do you expect it to be such).

Comment: Why are they `static`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are not printing the static variable in `payment2` but instead you are printing the local function variable

```
cout << "Worker: " << moneysamename << endl;
```

Since in the above line you did not use `this->` like you do in

```
this->moneysamename+= moneysamename;
```

You get the function local `moneysamename` and not the static member variable.  Change the output to

```
cout << "Worker: " << this->moneysamename << endl;
```

and you will get the same output.

The reason you do not get this in `payment1` is the function paramter has a different name then the static variable.  Had you made the function

```
virtual void payment1(float money) 
{
    this->money+= money;
    cout << "Worker: " << money << endl;
};
```

You would have had the same results.

Comment: @Rudi No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
virtual void payment2(float moneysamename) 
{
    this->moneysamename+= moneysamename;
    cout << "Worker: " << moneysamename << endl;
};
```

Here inside `payment2`, `moneysamename` will always refer to the function's first argument by C++ scoping rules (the nearest definition is taken). Hence, always the function's argument will be printed instead of the static protected variable of the parent class with the same name.
To print the local parent's variable you have to go to it's scope by `cout << "Worker: " << this->moneysamename << endl;`